# Laravel sync() method error

Tags: php, html, database, laravel

Short explanation of what I have:
a `ManyOnMany` relation between `project` and `user` using a pivot table called `project_user`.

When showing a certain project a list of users is printed with checkboxes so they will be linked to the project as soon as the checkbox is checked (so it will send the `user_id` + `project_id` to the `pivot table`

[image]

Now the problem. When we have the user (for example `Admin der Liam`) linked to the project it will work and the data will be send to the database.
But when the checkbox is unchecked again it will give a `Call to a member function users() on a non-object` error instead of clearing the table and putting only the checked boxes into the database

**Controller:**

```
public function edit($id, Project $project)
{
    $users = User::with('projects')->get();

    $project = $this->project->find($id);

    return view('project.edit', ['project' => $project, 'id' => 'edit', 'project_id' => $id, 'users' => $users]);  
}  


public function update(CreateProjectRequest $request)
{
    if($request->get('contribute'))
    {
        foreach($request->get('contribute') as $k => $contribute)
        {
            if($contribute == 1)
            {
                $project = $this->project->find($request->project_id);
                $keys[] = $k;
            }
        }
    }
    $project->users()->sync($keys);

    $project = $this->project->find($request->project_id);
    $project->fill($request->input())->save();

    return redirect('project');
}
```

**HTML/Blade:**

```
@if(isset($users))
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>
             {{$user->firstname}} {{$user->middlename}} {{$user->lastname}}
        </td>
        <td>
             {!! Form::checkbox('contribute['.$user->id.']', '1', $user->projects->contains($project->id)) !!}
        </td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: You call this $project->users()->sync($keys); before you initiate the $project object in the next line. That is why users() is not a member function.

Comment: So what is needed to change to make it work as wished?

Comment: Put the $project->users()->sync($keys); after the $project = $this->project->find($request->project_id); in your while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function update(CreateProjectRequest $request)
{
    $this->project = $this->project->find($request->project_id);
    if($request->get('contribute'))
    {
        foreach($request->get('contribute') as $k => $contribute)
        {
            if($contribute == 1)
            {
                $keys[] = $k;
            }
        }
    }

    if(isset($keys)) {
        $this->project->users()->sync($keys);
    }
    else {
        $this->project->users()->detach();
    }

    $this->project = $this->project->find($request->project_id);
    $this->project->fill($request->input())->save();

    return redirect('project');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $project is empty because you declared $project in the foreach.
Try to declare it outside the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `$project->users()->sync($keys);` after the `$project = $this->project->find($request->project_id);` in your while loop.
You should sync your $project after you have initialized the object.

```
foreach($request->get('contribute') as $k => $contribute)
{
    if($contribute == 1)
    {
        $project = $this->project->find($request->project_id);
        $keys[] = $k;
        $project->users()->sync($keys);
    }
}
```